# A way to track the situation with memory during creation and destruction of Prototype-beans in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, memory-management, prototype, javabeans

In a part of our project we have some number of prototype-beans. I would like to have a clear understanding of what is going on during execution of that part.

Is there **any way to track** the situation during creation of prototype-beans, what amount of memory they start using, and to track whether these beans were destroyed successfully?

I need not only printing the information in the console, but I would like to **see actual situation** with memory or the list of existing in memory prototype-beans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to **see the actual picture about created prototype-beans**.
I use free **VisualVM** memory profiler.

In the **Sampler** tab you can see all instances of created classes including singleton and prototype beans.

You'll see the names of your own packages and classes. In this case:

- **prototype** is a package with my prototype-beans.
- **singleton** is a package with my singleton-beans.
- **newclasses** is a package with classes that I created by **new** operator.

Also after the **garbage collector** will clean the memory you will see the result here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you need to do it programmatically , try with this [public interface Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html)

> This class provides services needed
>   to instrument Java programming language code. Instrumentation is the
>   addition of byte-codes to methods for the purpose of gathering data to
>   be utilized by tools. Since the changes are purely additive, these
>   tools do not modify application state or behavior. Examples of such
>   benign tools include monitoring agents, profilers, coverage analyzers,
>   and event loggers. There are two ways to obtain an instance of the
>   Instrumentation interface:
>
> When a JVM is launched in a way that indicates an agent class. In that
>   case an Instrumentation instance is passed to the premain method of
>   the agent class.
>
> When a JVM provides a mechanism to start agents sometime after the JVM
>   is launched. In that case an Instrumentation instance is passed to the
>   agentmain method of the agent code.

example [Instrumentation: querying the memory usage of a Java object](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml):

```
public class MyAgent {
  private static volatile Instrumentation globalInstr;
  public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
    globalInstr = inst;
  }
  public static long getObjectSize(Object obj) {
    if (globalInstr == null)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Agent not initted");
    return globalInstr.getObjectSize(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good stuff, I forgot about this. I would be careful with its usage in a production app though.

Comment: @ AnthonyJClink +1 )

Answer (score 1):

Any standard profiler would assist you in collecting the data you are looking for. For a quick and dirty look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

however I can help explain the prototype life cycle which may clarify some of your questions.

In most software solutions you have governing objects which generally are implemented as singletons, and you have data objects generally instantiated on need.

In spring, all beans created are marked as singletons and are internally managed by spring.

When you create a prototype bean, spring simply returns a new instance of that bean however it does manage the dependency injection of that bean.

so:

```
@Bean
public String importantString(){
    return "Super Important String used throughout the system";
}
```

When you require the important string in the prototype:

```
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyPrototypeBean{
    @Bean("importantString")
    private String myString;

    public String getString(){
      return importantString;
    }
}
```

Spring will cache the important string but your application will be now responsible for handling the prototype lifecycle as it would any new MyObject()

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    MyProtoTypeBean myPrototypeBean = context.getBean(MyPrototypeBean.class);

    MyProtoTypeBean myPrototypeBean2 = context.getBean(MyPrototypeBean.class);

   String importantString = myPrototypeBean.getString();

   // each prototoype is reconstructed
   assert myProtoTypeBean != myPrototypeBean2;       

   myPrototypeBean = null;
   myPrototypeBean2 = null;

  // Since we are now handling the lifecycle of the prototype beans, as soon 
  //as we clear them and set them to null garbage collection will clear the 
  //prototype beans but not the importantString singleton
  //however spring will still have reference to the singleton string

  assert importantString == context.getBean("importantString");
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have some knowledges of a life-cycle of singleton and prototype beans. My question is how exactly I can obtain the clear information or statistics of prototype-beans usage.

Comment: As stated, any standard profiler will give you this information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: Anthony, in a memory profiler I see that garbage collector clean all prototype beans from memory. Could you please explain in more details whether there are any reasons to destroy that beans manually by "=null" as shown in your example.

Comment: I did it manually for demonstration only... if I would have held them and continued with code... they would have been in the jvm due to referential integrity.. this was to show that the string singleton is still active and the prototypes are gone even in context.

Comment: Anthony, may be you can give a detailed good answer for my question about cleaning prototype beans from memory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548234/clarify-a-situation-with-a-cleaning-spring-prototype-beans-from-memory

Comment: @KirillCh I answered that question if you need any clarity feel free to reach out